# select count from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a tasks table with a `task_id` column and `parent_id` column for each task.
I am trying to build a query that returns for each `task_id`, the number of times this `id` shows in the parent `id` column.
I tried this query:

```
SELECT
     task_id, parent_id, 
     (SELECT COUNT( * ) 
      FROM  `tasks` 
      WHERE parent_id = task_id) AS count_parents 
FROM tasks
```

This query didn't work. I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: What was your error message? I suspect you need to add a GROUP BY clause, but am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to include all tasks whether they are ever a parent or not,

```
select tasks.task_id,count(parent.parent_id)
from tasks
left join tasks parent on tasks.task_id=parent.parent_id
group by tasks.task_id;
```

If you want only tasks that are parents, it is trivial:

```
select parent_id,count(*)
from tasks
group by parent_id;
```

(the latter possibly needing a `where parent_id is not null` or such, depending how you represent tasks that have no parent).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want this:

```
SELECT task_id, 
  parent_id, 
  COUNT(parent_id) AS count_parents
FROM tasks
GROUP BY task_id, parent_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select task_id,parent_id, count(parent_id) as count_parents 
from `tasks` 
group by task_id,parent_id;
```

In this case you need a group by, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.task_id, t2.parent_id, 
     (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tasks` t1 
         WHERE t1.parent_id = t2.task_id) AS count_parents 
 FROM tasks t2
```

I think from your question